# Convert array in JSON to list

Tags: c#, rest

Hello this is my JSON server :

http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=boys

I use REST API to create a new list based on data I want to get from JSON , this is the classes i created :

```
public class TVMazeModel
{
    public Show show { get; set; }
    public Rating rating { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
}

public class Show
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public decimal average { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string original { get; set; }
}
```

and the TVMazeController :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{searchText}")]
public IActionResult GetProductsExpensiveThan(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + searchText);

        var objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TVMazeModel>>(json);

        var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objResponse1);
        return Ok(json2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

when i run the server side and Browse in the Internet: https://localhost:44395/api/TVMaze/boys

this is what i got :

> [{"show":{"id":15299,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/15299/the-boys","name":"The
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":45235,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/45235/the-hardy-boys","name":"The
> Hardy
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":20222,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/20222/the-lost-boys","name":"The
> Lost
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":51384,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/51384/boys-lockdown","name":"Boys'
> Lockdown"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":1299,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1299/nowhere-boys","name":"Nowhere
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":41010,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/41010/gutta-boys","name":"Gutta
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":20891,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/20891/boys","name":"Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":31910,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/31910/boys","name":"Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":1522,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1522/mrs-browns-boys","name":"Mrs.
> Brown's
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null},{"show":{"id":1265,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1265/angry-boys","name":"Angry
> Boys"},"rating":null,"image":null}]

So why is rating is null and image is null ?

The part of the show works great, just have a problem with them ..

I want to get the rating.average and image.original like the classes i wrote above ...

Comment: Can you add what do you get from the third party URL ?

Comment: I've already added it, in a row: "this is what i got :"

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your post. That is what you got from http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q= right¿?

Comment: Why you want to convert json string to C# class, you can pass the response directly to frontend?

Comment: `image` is not part of `TVMazeModel` but `Show` ... should be downvoted and closed as typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the response I've got from https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=a I realized that Image and Rating are behind show, so you have to create your TVMazeModel with the same structure than your third URL response.

Try this:

```
    public class TVMazeModel
    {
        public Show show { get; set; }   
    }
    
    public class Show
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Rating rating { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
    }
    public class Rating
    {
        public decimal average { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string original { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add image and rating property in show class

public Rating rating { get; set; }
public Image image { get; set; }